# GPA calculator assistance

Tags: java

Hi I was wondering if I could get some help with a GPA calculator.

What it needs to do is:

1. The input will consist of a sequence of terms, e.g., semesters.
2. The input for each term will consist of grades and credits for courses taken within that term.
3. For each term, the user will type in an integer that represents the number of courses
   taken within that term.
4. Each course is specified by a String letter grade and an int number of credits, in that order, separated by white space. 5.  If the user types in -1 for the number of courses taken in a term, then the program must print a final overall summary and then terminate.
5. DO  NOT  prompt  for  any  input.   Thus, after  you  run  your  program  in  BlueJ, type Ctrl-T to force the Terminal window to pop up.
6. As always, follow the input / output format depicted in the Sample runs section.

Shown below is the error message I get and the code I have, thank you for any assistance in advance or tips I could try.

Terminal window and error message:
[image: Terminal]

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/*
* 
* 
*/
public class Prog2 { 

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner numberInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numberofClasses = numberInput.nextInt();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] grade = new String[5];
    int [] credit = new int [5];
    double totalCredit = 0.0;
    double realGrade = 0.0;
    double result = 0.0;

    while (numberofClasses > 0) 
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < numberofClasses; x++ )
        { 
            grade[x] = input.next();

            credit[x] = input.nextInt();

        }
        for(int x=0;x < numberofClasses; x++ ){
            if(grade[x].equals("A+")){
                realGrade=4.0;              
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("A")){
                realGrade=4.0;
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("A-")){
                realGrade=3.67;         
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("B+")){
                realGrade=3.33;         
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("B")){
                realGrade=3.00;         
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("B-")){
                realGrade=2.67;         
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("C+")){
                realGrade=2.33;         
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("C")){
                realGrade=2.00;         
            }
            else if(grade[x].equals("C-")){
                realGrade=1.33;         
            }

            result = result+realGrade*credit[x];
            totalCredit=totalCredit+credit[x];
        }
        System.out.println("Summary for term:");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Term total grade points: " + result);
        System.out.println("Term total credits:" + totalCredit);
        System.out.println("GPA:"+result/totalCredit);


    }
        // This block is getting used later please ignore
        System.out.println("Final Summary:");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println(" Overall terms");
        System.out.println(" Total grade points: " + result);// this needs to be all );
        System.out.println(" Total credits" + totalCredit);//This needs to be all );
        System.out.println("Cumulative GPA:"+result/totalCredit);  

  }
}
```

Comment: PS: some cosmetics for your exercise: you have some spaces to much in your println summary. always without leading space `("Term` or with leading space `(" Total`. and always with following space after `: "` or without `:"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your while loop ends, numberofClasses still contains the value that was entered before the while loop started the first time. Specifically, after you output the line:

```
GPA=3.0588...
```

you hit the end of the loop, then return to:

```
while (numberofClasses > 0)
```

which is true. The next "3" that you enter doesn't go into numberofClasses, it is picked up by

```
grade[x] = input.next();
```

Then the "A" is picked up by

```
credit[x] = input.nextInt();
```

which throws an exception since it's not an integer.

All you need to do is ask for the number of classes again at the end of the while loop:

```
    System.out.println("GPA:"+result/totalCredit);
    numberofClasses = numberInput.nextInt();
}
```

Output:

```
5
A 3
B 2
C 4
A 5
C 3
Summary for term:
----------------------------------
Term total grade points: 52.0
Term total credits:17.0
GPA:3.0588235294117645
3
A 3
B 5
C 1
Summary for term:
----------------------------------
Term total grade points: 81.0
Term total credits:26.0
GPA:3.1153846153846154
```

Comment: I have another question if you wouldn't mind helping a tad bit more. When I go through the loop a second time and print out the GPA, credit, etc... Is there a way that i can only print out the data used on that loop and not the cumulative totals entered?

Comment: reset the variables to zero when you enter the next loop

Comment: Thank you both for your help!

Comment: When thinking about these problems, you might start with pencil and paper and write down the logic of the problem you're trying to solve first. Come up with 2 or 3 ways to solve the problem, choose one, then fire up the PC and think about writing code. At this point you can compare what your code does to what your pencil/paper prescribed, and you'll be better able to debug things.

Answer (score 0):

i recommend looking into whether your compiler or IDE has a "debug" feature.  It is a very helpful tool, and lets you watch how your program goes through your code

Just a tip...

When you ask for input, print what you're asking for first.  When I launched your program I had no idea what to do.  Try adding `System.out.println("input number of classes you took");`before you prompt for that number.

Here is what is wrong.  (If you printed what you're asking for first, this would be more apparent).

after your program displays the stats, you enter 5.  Yet your program is actually still on this line `grade[x] = input.next();` on line 22 i believe.

when you enter 5, your scanner is expecting a letter.  and an exception is thrown.

you need to consider how you escape this loop here. `while (numberofClasses > 0)` perhaps use an if statement?  otherwise your program loops for forever, never asking for a new class number

Comment: The parameters for the program are specifically to not prompt the user otherwise I would.